# play multiple sound files max msp

Tags: audio-interfaces, max-msp

I have a sound card (fca610 – Behringer) with multiple outputs and have three audio files (mono).

I am trying to play each audio file on different channel.
Inn max I have added a DAC for audio output and set the output device of the DAC to the sound card and made sure all channels are visible (see screenshot).
[image]

I added a playlist for the audio files but I am not sure how to play each audio file on a different output channel. See below the patch I made but I don't really know why its not working or how to make it work.
[image]

I am very new to max.
If you need any clarification, let me know!